# Templating a JavaScript function in Jinja

Tags: javascript, jinja2

I have this function in my script:

```
function DoThing (num){
 //Do thing
});
```

`num` refers to each item in a list I created earlier in the script. `DoThing(1)` will activate for the first item and so on.

I'm working with a Jinja2 template for a multi-page website, and I want to put the function with a custom `num` argument in each template.

In the first page, I would have DoThing(1). Second page would be DoThing(2). My goal is to add new items and have the template update as needed based on the length of my list.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `num` variable in the beginning of your template:

```
{% set num = 1 %}
```

and call your Javascript function like:

```
<script>
    DoThing({{ num }});
</script>
```